# Pumping Lemma proof, need help with splitting xyz word, choosing pumping length and proving its not regular

Tags: solution-verification, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I have the following language i want to prove is not regular by using the pumping lemma but not sure on what to use as the xyz and the pumping length. can i get a point in the right direction for how to prove it is not regular.
{z^7n c^5 c^n+7 c^m | n,m >= 0}
i have tried condensing it down to z^7n c^n+m + 12
but dont know what word to pump down, as pumping up will just keep increasing m value.

Comment: To be clear, this is $$\left\{z^{7n}c^5c^{n+7}c^m:n,m\ge 0\right\}\,?$$ If so, take $p$ as the pumping length, and start with $w=z^{7p}c^{p+12}$, i.e., with $n=p$ and $m=0$; all of the pumping will take place in the $z$ part.

Comment: yes this the correct equation, still unsure how to pump after this.

Comment: more specifically how to split into xyz

Comment: You don’t get to say how it splits into $x,y$, and $u$. (I’m using $u$ instead of $z$, because $z$ is one of the letters in the alphabet for this language.) The **only** things that you can assume about the split are that $|xy|\le p$ and $|y|\ge 1$. From that information alone you have to show that there is some $k\ge 0$, such that $xy^ku$ is not in the language. And in this case that’s easy, because $k=1$ is the only value of $k$ for which $xy^ku$ **is** in the language: changing $k$ by $1$ changes the number of $z$s without changing the number of $c$s.

Comment: sorry to keep questioning , but how would i translate this into a proof

Comment: something like this 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069389/prove-that-the-language-is-not-regular-using-pumping-lemma?rq=1
explains it in an easier format :)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571324/pumping-lemma-clarification-of-usage/571338#571338) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697244/using-pumping-lemma-to-prove-a-language-not-regular/1697273#1697273) are two pumping lemma arguments worked out in full detail.